# I want to create a folder with three new folders inside it

Tags: php

I want to create a folder, 'folderA', and inside of 'folderA' I want to create 'folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3'.

I don't know how to do this. I have tried to change the code to form a list with three: users folerA folder1, users folderA folder2, users folderA folder3, all in the same parentheses but that didn't work.

I have also tried to create users folderA folder1 and that didn't work either. Have I written enough to be able to submit my question yet?

```
if (!file_exists("users/folderA")) {
    mkdir("users/folderA", 0755);
}
```

This creates folderA, but now how do I get three folders inside folderA?

Comment: `for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) { mkdir('users/folderA/folder' . $i, 0755); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way you write all by yourself

```
if (!file_exists("users/folderA")) {
    mkdir("users/folderA", 0755);
    mkdir('users/folderA/folder1',755);
    mkdir('users/folderA/folder2',755);
    mkdir('users/folderA/folder3',755);
}
```

Or you use a loop

```
if (!file_exists("users/folderA")) {
      mkdir("users/folderA", 0755);
   for ($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) 
   { 
   mkdir('users/folderA/folder'.$i, 0755); 
   }
}
```